# C++11: Universal executor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading, overload-resolution

I would to know how get this code compiles:

```
// test3.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                      

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename R, typename... rArgs>
R universal_exer(R(*f)(rArgs...), rArgs... args)
{
    return (*f)(forward<rArgs>(args)...);
}

int addition(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int addition(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template<typename... Args>
int addition(int a, int b, Args... args)
{
    return a + b + addition(args...);
}

int main()
{
    cout << universal_exer(&addition, 1) << endl;
}
```

Error message (gcc 4.7.2):

```
test3.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test3.cpp:31:40: error: no matching function for call to 'universal_exer(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)'
test3.cpp:31:40: note: candidate is:
test3.cpp:8:3: note: template<class R, class ... rArgs> R universal_exer(R (*)(rArgs ...), rArgs ...)
test3.cpp:8:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test3.cpp:31:40: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'R'
```

How can I indicate the correct overload of the `addition` function?

Comment: Cast it to the right pointer(helps for overloads) or use a lambda, there is a dupe somewhere.

Comment: try this `cout << universal_exer(static_cast<int (*)(int)>(&addition), 1) << endl;` 
[example](https://godbolt.org/g/fLMZRm)

Answer (score 5):

Replace your main with

```
int main()
{
    int (*f)(int) = &addition;
    cout << universal_exer(f, 1) << endl;

    // or alternatively
    // cout << universal_exer((int (*)(int))addition, 1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Specifically, the solution to `unresolved overloaded function type` is to resolve *which* overloaded function it is.  That's being done here.