# C++11/templates: Select the correct overloading of a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, word-wrap, overloading

In relation with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506427/c11-universal-executor), that perhaps is too much oversimplified, I give here a more complex example. The problem that I pretend is depicted with the following code:

```
// test3.cpp

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct exer
{
    template<typename R, typename... rArgs, typename... pArgs>
    R operator()(R(T::*f)(rArgs...), pArgs&&... args)
    {
       return (t.*f)(forward<pArgs>(args)...);
    }

    T t;
};

struct A
{
    int addition() { return 0; }

    template<typename... Args>
    int addition(int a, Args... args) { return a + addition(args...); }
};

struct B
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    int addition(Args&&... args)
    {
       return m_e(&A::addition, forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    exer<A> m_e;
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    cout << b.addition(1, 2, 3, 4) << endl;
}
```

This problem here is, in the instantation of `B::addition`, the type of `&A::addition` isn't known because different overloads exists. Moreover, `B::addition` doesn't know also which overload must be used. This doesn't know the compiler until the function is called. But, in order to correctly specify wich overload must be used in `exer<A>::operator()`, I need to make a casting of `&A::addition` to cast it to the correct overload.

How can I extract the type of the correct overload of the target function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the question.  If you can make `exer` take a callable object instead of a pointer to member function, like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct exer
{
    T t;
    template<typename F, typename... pArgs>
    auto operator()(F f, pArgs&&... args)
    -> decltype(f(t, forward<pArgs>(args)...))
    {
       return f(t, forward<pArgs>(args)...);
    }

};
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
struct B
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    int addition(Args&&... args)
    {
        struct Invoker {
            auto operator()(A& a, Args&&... args) const
                ->decltype(a.addition(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
            { return a.addition(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
        };
        return m_e(Invoker(), forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    exer<A> m_e;
};
```

Now selecting the correct `A::addition` is done by the compiler using the normal overload resolution rules.

Instead of `Invoker` you could use a lambda expression, which reduces some of the repetition:

```
        return m_e( [](A& a, Args&&... as) {
                      return a.addition(forward<Args>(as)...);
                    },
                    forward<Args>(args)...);
```